# Bootstrap 4: Display an icon when .table-responsive becomes horizontally scrollable

Tags: responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I'm building a Rails app with Bootstrap 4. I have a number of large tables to display and since the app users are not very tech-savvy I would like to display a hint when a full table doesn't fit their screen and becomes scrollable. Any tips on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `alert` with `class="something"`.

```
<div class="alert alert-primary something" role="alert">
  The table is scrollable!!!
</div>
```

Then, In the CSS file you can do:

```
.something{
  display: none;
}
```

Then also write a media query to update the `something` class to display block.

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .something{
      display: block;
    }
}
```

Result: It'll not display the alert until the window size reduced to 576px.

Comment: Thanks @Emu, however this does not resolve my problem. I don't want the alert to be dependent on a media query, but on the fakt that a table actually became scrollable, and this will differ for each table.